# How many times should I call firebase.analytics()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-analytics

When using Firestore, I see people using this pattern:

```
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

And then use the `db` reference across the app to access the Firestore interface.

But I don't usually do this. I prefer to use it like:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("myCollection").get()   // I USE IT LIKE THIS ACROSS THE APP
```

Whenever I need Firestore, I always call `firebase.firestore()`

Basically I'm getting the same reference over and over again to the [Cloud Firestore service interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html).

And it works just fine.

---

**QUESTION**

Can the same concept be applied to the `firebase.analytics()` call?

**I.e:** can I call it multiple times throughout my app (like the Firestore example) or will I be logging the same default events over and over again on each call?

Like: calling `firebase.analytics()` everytime I need the Analytics interface.

Because I know that just by calling it once, you're already logging (sending) out some default events.

Would it make any difference to use it like this:

```
export const analytics = firebase.analytics();
```

And then use the `analytics` to log events, instead of `firebase.analytics().logEvent()` everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase.analytics()` just returns a singleton object, the same every time.  All of the Firebase product entrypoints exposed by the `firebase` object are all that way.  Whatever method you want to use to get that singleton object is completely up to you.